# Что лучше - хранить json в memcached или разместить его в базе?

Tags: php, postgresql, memcached

Есть один json-файл весом в 1,5 мегабайта, в котором хранится информация о городах. Например:

```
[{'code': 'MOW', 'name': 'Москва', 'name_translations': {...}, 'country_code': 'RU'}]
```

И так далее. Сейчас у меня алгоритм работает таким образом:

1. При загрузке страницы проверяется, нет ли в memcached данных с ключом этого json
2. Если есть, то происходит проверка на то, не изменился ли сам файл (посредством `filemtime()`)
3. Если есть, то из memcached поднимается строка, которая декодируется в многомерный массив и дальше с ним уже происходят дальнейшие операции.

Но с этим алгоритмом есть ряд проблем. Во-первых, в memcached ограниченное количество памяти (в моём случае 128 мегабайт). И в неё регулярно что-то пишется, перезаписывая ключи. При определённом количестве перезаписей указанный json удаляется из memcached и алгоритму вновь приходится открывать локальный файл и присваивать его содержимое ключу в memcached. Во-вторых, всё вышеуказанное занимает буфер (т.е. место в оперативной памяти) и постоянно долбит диск открывая различные файлы.

**Вопрос:** будет ли лучше производительность, если я перенесу этот json в базу данных и буду работать только с ней напрямую (без прокладок в виде `file_get_contents()` и `json_decode()`). По факту ведь это обыкновенная статика и делать в базе ей нечего. В общем, как лучше поступить?

Comment: у меня информация о городах находится в базе(~27 000 записей) найти нужный  город или подредактировать быстрее из базы нежели из фала. памяти PHP точно будет меньше потреблять.

Comment: декодировать 1.5мб json сомнительная затея. Да и вообще при наличии БД не ясно зачем вообще хранить это файлом.

Comment: memcache: все хранит в памяти, скорость максимальная. как заметили, проблема с промахами кеша. файл: чтение с диска, но не всегда, ОС кеширует данные какое-то время. БД: имеет свою систему управления памяти, цель - минимизация обращения к диску. Получается такая градация по среднестатистическому количеству обращений к диску: memcache < db < file_get_contents. Но. Если вы серьезно бьетесь с производительностью приложения, добавляйте памяти везде - в мемкеш, в БД. Обычно делают так: сначала мемкеш, потом лезут в БД

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна производительность, лучше хранить в in-memory database, для подобного случая идеально бы зашел tarantool ну или redis со своими хэш-таблицами. Но если ограничиваться 128Мб мапяти то лучше держать это на диске либо в реляционной БД либо тот же самый tarantool положить на диск а не в память.

Все зависит от доступного стека сервисов.

Еще в зависимости от того как используются эти данные, т.е. нужно забирать данные о городе по какому-либо параметру или нужно забирать всегда все города и.т.д. можно понять в каком виде это складывать в хранилище и как построить индексы.

В любом случае собирать и разбирать большой json это дорогая по ресурсам операция которую можно легко избежать. А хранить эти данные в memcached точно лучше не стоит.